# Repository by using python

Tags: python

I have made a repository or a contact book using python:

But i am only able to use search function on one name at a time so i want to write code in such a way that i can search multiple name and related contact info at the same time.

```
num=int(input("Total no. of repository user wants to create: "))
names=[]
contact_numbers=[]
for i in range(num):
    name = input("Enter the Name: ")
    contact_number = input("Enter the Phone Number: ")

    names.append(name)
    contact_numbers.append(contact_number)

print("\n\tName\t\t\tPhone Number\n")

#Creating a list of names & contact in tabular form:

for i in range(num):
    print("\t{}\t\t\t{}".format(names[i], contact_numbers[i]))

#Search:

while True:
    choice=int(input("\n\nPress 1 or 2\n1=To search\n2=To Exit\n"))
    if choice == 1:
        search_name=input("\n Enter the name you want to search: ")
        print("\nSEARCH RESULT :")
        if search_name in names:
            index = names.index(search_name)
            contact_number = contact_numbers[index]
            print("Name: {}, Phone Number: {}".format(search_name, contact_number))
            
        else:
            print("Name not found in repository")
            
    else:
        print("Exit")
        break
```

Comment: Ask user to input a list of names to search. Maybe use comma delimited string. Split the string appropriately then search. By the way, using two discrete lists is quite wrong. Sure it will work but it's not practically extensible. Consider using a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this greatly by using the most appropriate structures. In this case a dictionary is ideal.

```
contacts = {}

while (name := input('Enter name or <return> when finished: ')):
    phone_number = input('Enter phone number: ')
    contacts[name] = phone_number

while (names := input('Enter name or comma-separated list of names to search or <return> when finished: ')):
    for name in names.split(','):
        print(f'{name} {contacts.get(name, "Not found")}')
```